# putting JS apply to work

Tags: javascript

Trying to understand apply and thought I got it until I hit this.

Can some one explain why the 3rd option in the below code works and not the 1st or 2nd.

To me it seems similar but I must be missing something.

HTML

```
      <input type="button" id="submitButton" value="check me">
```

and the JS code

```
            function createDelegate(object, method)
            {
                var shim = function()
                            {
                                method.apply(object, arguments);
                            }

                return shim;
            }

            function MagicButtonManager(buttonId, message)
            {
                this._message = message;
                var btn = document.getElementById(buttonId);

               var shimx = function()
                            {
                                this.showMessage.apply(this, arguments);
                            }
               // btn.onclick = shimx;  // 1st
               // btn.onclick = function() { this.showMessage.apply(this, arguments);}   // 2nd
                btn.onclick = createDelegate(this, this.showMessage); // 3rd - only this works
            }

            MagicButtonManager.prototype.showMessage = function()
            {
                alert(this._message);
            }

            var m = new MagicButtonManager('submitButton', 'Hello World!');

            //m();   // also why does the btn.onlick binding not happens with this line if we remove the new from previous line?
```

I have put it through as a fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/4TLKC/17/

can someone shed some light. Thanks.

edit : changed title word to apply from closure( was a mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the value of 'this' is determine by the context in which a function is invoked. In both #1 and #2 the value of this will be the button DOM element. In order to make 'this' the MagicButtonManager instance you need to capture the value in a closure.

A closure is a function that contains another function, and neither #1 or #2 are closures. When you create a closure the inner function captures variables from the outer scope. In option #3 the shim function captures the 'object' that is passed in from the outer scope, which happens to be the value for 'this' that you want.

Or, for a simpler alternative, you could use the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function, if you can assume IE9 and above.

Comment: Thanks, I think this answers my query best. Was also reading up on closures(link below, that references the code stub mentioned above) and your point on it is also helpful.
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/10/closure-on-javascript-closures.aspx
JS apply
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/putting-function-apply-to-work.aspx
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe methods #1 and #2 do not work because you can't use `this` in the body of a function declared on the spot. In other words, this won't work:

```
var myfunction = function() { this.whatever(); };
```

But this will:

```
var me = this;
var myfunction = function() { me.whatever(); };
```

With method #3, `this` is actually passed as an argument to the `createDelegate` method, thus resolving the problem in the same way.

Note that calling the `.bind(this)` method on the function will do the same thing.

Comment: You can use 'this' wherever you like. It is simply a pointer.

Comment: This solution resolves the problem though. I do believe that `this` is no longer valid when used outside the scope of a class, as in the case of dynamically declared functions.

Comment: You should use the `bind` function to preserve the `this` pointer... `function() { //... }.bind(this)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind this to shim in the first one like below

```
 btn.onclick = shimx.bind(this);  // 1st
```

And for second one

`btn.onclick = function() { this.showMessage.apply(this, arguments);}.bind(this);`

Explanation to this is same as given by ColinE, and yes this is not to do anything with closure

Comment: Thanks mate. This additional info helps.